# Filling XML with loops in PHP

Tags: php, xml, loops

I got the following code but nothing happens, I can't find a good tutorial on filling XML with multiple loops:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$xml_user = $xml->createElement("User");
$xml_user->setAttribute("Name", $username);
foreach ($alben as $album) {
    $i = 1;
    $xml_album = $xml->createElement("Album");
    $pictures = $picture_object->get_all_pictures($album['id']);
    $xml_user->appendChild($xml_album);

    $xml_album->setAttribute("Name", $album['name']);
    foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
        $xml_picture = $xml->createElement("Picture");
        $xml_album->appendChild($xml_picture);
        $xml_picture->setAttribute("Name", $picture['name']);
        $rating = $rating_object->get_picture_rating($picture['id']);
        $xml_rating = $xml->createElement("Rating");
        $xml_picture->appendChild($xml_rating);
        $comments = $comment_object->get_all_comments($picture['id']);
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            $xml_comment = $xml->createElement("Kommentar");
            $xml_picture->appendChild($xml_comment);
            $xml_comment->setAttribute("Datum", $comment['date']);
            $xml_comment->nodeValue($comment['text']);
        }
    }
}

$xml->save("myXML.xml");
```

Comment: did you write this? just check the output `myXML.xml`

Comment: maybe you dont have write permission on your directory. Before save try to see what is generated? Then save.

Comment: also where are you using $username?

Comment: username is the current logged in user i want to print all his albums and pictures to xml in the .xml i only get the xml "header" with versionnr ...